# Custom Taxonomy Term page in Drupal 7

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7, drupal-taxonomy

I'm trying to make a custom Taxonomy Term page in Drupal 7. I've created a page--taxonomy.tpl.php file in my templates folder. The file only prints out a message. I now try to force the template file by adding

```
function template_preprocess_page($variables) {
  if (arg(0) == 'taxonomy') {
    $variables['template_file'] = 'page--taxonomy-tpl';
  }
}
```

in my template.php, but it won't work. Can you help me? And if I get the custom page working, how do I fetch the nodes with this term (in page--taxonomy.tpl.php)? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try using this in your template.php:

```
function template_preprocess_page(&$variables) {
  if (arg(0) == 'taxonomy') {
    $variables['theme_hook_suggestions'][] = 'page__taxonomy';
  }
}
```

- You need to pass `$variables` by reference, so add a & before it
- `template_file` has changed to `theme_hook_suggestions` in Drupal 7
- You don't need the `-tpl` in the template suggestion unless you want it to be a part of the filename like "page--taxonomy-tpl.tpl.php" which I don't think is what you want.

For more information, check out [template_preprocess_page()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--theme.inc/function/template_preprocess_page/7), [theme_get_suggestions()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--theme.inc/function/theme_get_suggestions/7) and [Working with template suggestions](http://drupal.org/node/223440)

Comment: Thanks mate - it works! However is this the best approach for a custom Taxonomy page? I would like to use all the regions of my template, and just make a custom "main content". Does this make sense? This template will just overwrite everything..

Comment: @s0mmer I think this is the way it has to be done.  It is creating a layout for the whole page, not just the main content.  So if you want all your normal regions and such, open page.tpl.php and copy/paste it into page--taxonomy.tpl.php, then from there you can customize however you like and will have your normal regions, etc

Answer (score 3):

Not sure if this would meet your requirements, but one of default D7 views - Taxonomy term - emulates Drupal core's handling of taxonomy/term pages. You could just enable it (it would automatically replace Drupal's core taxonomy URLs), and then do whatever you want with it, keeping original page structure, all blocks etc, using Views' page templates (see "Theming information" in "Advanced") and all other bells and whistles...

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using **Drupal 7**, you could also create a file name **"taxnomy-term.tpl.php"** and edit according to your needs.

See [taxonomy-term.tpl.php](http://drupal.org/node/190815)

Answer (score 0):

Full control over the taxonomy term page can be obtained using hook_menu_alter() . See https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/48420/theming-and-overriding-taxonomy-term-vocabulary-page/111194#111194